# Mask on images to prevent copying

Tags: php, image, png, block, masking

There is on internet. Such script that, "jumps" before an another image.
So... for example, if I found an image, and I click on "Save as..." I get a 1x1 pixel image in place of the one I wanted to safe.

For example of it is
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0
Next to views counter (1'167'974'545) there is an animation. But if I try to copy link or save it, it "push" into my hands useless picture. This script could be very useful on my website. How to do it?

Comment: It's quite simple and it's quite simple to work-around. Just stack two images on top of each other.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes it easy to work-around. But, I don't think that about 60% of internet users knows how. You may install many tools around website, and this will increase to 85% ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from the code of the youtube page they use the following lines as the html elemnt for that image:

```
<img class="watch-dancing-psy" src="//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif">
```

So normally the image referred to in the `src` attribute is the 1x1 pixel image.

They use CSS to put the real image like this (when defining the CSS class `watch-dancing-psy`):

```
background-image: url(https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/logo_dancing_psy-vflsJl9hC.gif);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of your example URL `img src` is a 1x1px transparent gif and the "actual" image and its dimensions are defined in CSS as `background`, `width` and `height` properties.